# How to use a uuid in a mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb

In our java project we can get a MongoDb record by uuid using Spring MongoRepository findById method:

```
repository.findById(uuid); //uuid= UUID.fromString("950a52be-94e3-481d-9d3e-e974de59354a)"
```

But is there possibility to use uuid in MongoDb query?

This works:

```
{_id: Binary("HUjjlL5SCpVKNVnedOk+nQ==", 3)}
```

But is there possibility to query, using uuid?

```
{_id:"950a52be-94e3-481d-9d3e-e974de59354a"}
```

Comment: Can you try: `{_id:UUID("950a52be-94e3-481d-9d3e-e974de59354a")}` ?

Comment: Get a message "Query entered is not valid" in Mongo Express.

Answer (score 0):

This works: `{_id:UUID("950a52be-94e3-481d-9d3e-e974de59354a")}`